# No replies and expiring bounty

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

I currently have a question up here: [Optimizing Python Image Viewer and General Code Format Advise](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/optimizing-python-image-viewer-and-general-code-format-advise). Currently there are no answers, and the faq states "In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty". Does this mean I will lose 50 of my rep points even though nobody has answered my question?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed it does per https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

> In any case, you will *always* give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

I suggest sharing a link to the question with any friends or colleagues who might be interested in viewing your code -- or broadcast it on Twitter, Facebook, etc using the sharing links on the question.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

Comment: Can't post your own answer to the question and let the bounty be awarded to yourself?

Comment: not any more, you can't -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty